# How to cast from array of parent class containing children back to parent

Tags: java, list, class, inheritance, casting

I have a list of `Parent` that holds child classes of `Parent`, e.g. `Child1` or `Child2`. I now want to get an element from there by going

```
public <T> T getChild(Class<T> tClass)
{
    for(Parent i: parents)
    {
        if(i.getClass==tClass)
        {
            return(T)i;
        }
    }
    return(null);
}
```

However, for some reason this is returning null even when I go `parents.add(new Child1());` before calling the function. If you have a solution it would be very welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't it be if(i.getClass()==tClass.getClass()) ?

Comment: nope, that errors out.

Comment: more likely `if (i.getClass() == tClass)` ... but posted code should not even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me, although I'm not certain that it is what you are looking for.

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Parent {
    private static List<? extends Parent>  parents;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T getChild(Class<T> childClass) {
        for (Parent i : parents) {
            if (i.getClass().equals(childClass)) {
                return (T) i;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child1 c1 = new Child1();
        Child2 c2 = new Child2();
        Parent p = new Parent();
        parents = List.of(p, c2, c1);
        System.out.println(getChild(c2.getClass()));
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
    
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    
}
```

When I run the above code, the output is

```
Child2@34c45dca
```

Refer to
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html
and
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: How can I do this without having to use ```c2.getClass()```. I want to be able to do ```Child2.class```

Comment: @BossCode `Child2.class` and `c2.getClass()` will both give you the same `Class<?>`.

Comment: Actually no, this does work, I was just implementing the code wrong. Sorry for a dumb question.

Comment: Notes: 1) `equals` is not needed,  `==` works with classes; 2) to avoid unchecked cast `return childClass.cast(i);`